# How to host an API 2.0 in another project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I've created an API that fetch data from database and then I added another project and added this API as a reference to that project, I created a simple JavaScript function to fetch the data from that referenced API. I can't find the exact path

and It shows this error
**"NetworkError: 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed -http //localhost:29440/api/purchase/"**

First Is this the wright way to call that API function With JavaScript (

```
var uri = 'http://localhost:29440/api/purchase';
```

)
If it is then why do we need to tell the exact location of the API isn't that a security Issue.

Second It says some thing about the CORS, I checked a project on asp.net web about this core and self hosting but nothing works as give, I tried To host them on same localhost address But that Didn't worked either

and yes Tried that CONSOLE stuff to, same sh** no progress

So please guide me through this

Regards

Comment: have tried enabling cors from webapiconfig file?

Comment: @qamar yes that one too also with jquery as I saw in a project jquery.support.cors=true

Comment: can u show me your fiddler response when you call API

Comment: [Link](http://prntscr.com/5pjvxo) Do you mean This

Comment: Its seems like cors issue. can i see ur webapiconfig file? and are you using owin middleware?

Comment: I tried to host them on same localhost/domain too but it still shows that message also made changes to the web.config as given in this tutorial [link](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1366/building-rest-api-with-mvc-4-web-api-part-3)

Comment: In one of my project I solved the issue by adding these lines in the webapiconfig.cs file and inside it there is a method called register. config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")); Note that I did not enable cors from web config as the article states. And also you need to add cors package from nuget in your project. Serach Cors you should get that. The assembly name is using System.Web.Http.Cors;

Comment: As I said Mr Qamar I did all that as accordingly also tried my self on the same domain but that didn't help, still thank you for the help

Comment: If you have tried everything and did not work then I guess its beyond fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this First I added the cors refrence from nuget that was, microsoft.asp.webapi.cors
Than I changed my WebApiConfig File in App_Start
I enabled core there like this `config.EnableCors();`
Then I enabled Cors on my Controller to which I wanted to expose Like this

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:33069", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class PurchaseController : ApiController
```

Hope This Help Others Too